# Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'Double'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Учусь свифту, пытаюсь как первое приложение сделать конвертер величин.
При попытке перевести миллиметры в сантиметры выдает ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По разному пытался извращаться, чтобы заработало, все равно выдает ошибки

```
@IBOutlet weak var kilometr_textfield: UITextField!
@IBAction func milimetr_textfield(_ sender: UITextField) {
    let milimetr:Double = Double((milimetr_textfield?.text)!)!
    if (milimetr != 0.0) {
        santimetr_textfield.text = 10.0 * milimetr


    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30676813/1016033

Comment: И ещё, что бы из миллиметров получить сантиметры надо делить на 10, а не умножать.

Comment: Так же подозреваю, что в последнем примере ошибка уже другая. Я не знаю свифт, но мне кажется, что он не даст вам присвоить текстовому полю `.text` значение `Double` без явного приведения типов.

Comment: @AlexeyTen "И ещё, что бы из миллиметров получить сантиметры надо делить на 10, а не умножать" - это новая система единиц измерений?

Comment: @VAndrJ не понял. 10мм = 1см. У вас не так?

Comment: @AlexeyTen ох что-то меня переклинило, извиняюсь :)

Comment: @AlexeyTen вырвал из контекста "сантиметры надо делить на 10", а дальше все как в тумане

Answer (score 1):

uitextfield.text может принимать только значения типа string.
попробуйте обернуть выражение в string:

```
santimetr_textfield.text = String(10.0 * milimetr)
```

Comment: Второй вариант `santimetr_textfield.text = "\(10.0 * milimetr)"`